# How to implement back button functionality of android in Sencha Touch using cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, sencha-touch-2.1

I have searched a lot on this topic. But till now I could not find a proper solution. I want to implement back button functionality of android in Sencha Touch using cordova.

**I have 2 views**

One.js

Two.js

Inside One.js I have a button. On clicking the button I go to the Two.js using the   following code.

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('Appname.view.Two'));
```

Now with the help of cordova I am able to detect back button press by writing the following code in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("In device");
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
 function onBackKeyDown() {
        alert("hello");
    }

    </script>
```

So what piece of code should I write inside onBackKeyDown, so that when the user presses back buton when in Two.js, it should return to One.js

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the same function to bring you to the second page?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("In device");
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('Appname.view.One'));
}
```